# Show $c_n= (1 + \vert a_n \vert)^{b_n + {1 \over n}}$ satifies the Cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisfy the Cauchy criterion, then $(c_n)$ where $c_n= (1 + \vert a_n \vert)^{b_n + {1 \over n}}$ also satisfies this criterion.

My suspicion is that we might have to consider
$$\vert c_m - c_k \vert = \left\vert (1 + \vert a_m \vert)^{b_m + {1 \over m}} - (1 + \vert a_k \vert)^{b_k + {1 \over k}}\right\vert$$
and show it is bounded from above by some simpler expression. Do you have any clues?

Comment: In $\Bbb{R},$ Cauchy$\iff$ Convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is equivalent, for any complex sequence, to be a convergent sequence or to be a Cauchy sequence  then it is sufficient to see that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
c_n= (1 + \vert a_n \vert)^{b_n + {1 \over n}}=e^{(b_n+\frac1n)\cdot \log (1 + \vert a_n \vert)} \to e^{b\cdot \log (1 + |a|)}=(1+|a|)^b
$$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n=b$.